# How client movement prediction syncs with server position to avoid a clip around collision?

Tags: collision-detection, client-server, collision-prediction

I have searched a lot on stackexchange and on google, yet I have not found a satisfactory answer to this seemingly simple question.

I am making an online multiplayer game where the players navigate a 2d map with basic square obstacles. In this case I am making collision checks both on the client and the server, where the server broadcast everyone's position once per second as authority. However, when making a sharp turn around a square, often times either the client makes the turn while the server clips, or the client clips at the corner while the server makes the turn. That is understandable considering the possible discrepancy between the position on the server and the predictive position of the client. How do online multiplayer games usually work around this simple yet crucial problem?

I understand that it comes down to a pixel perfect sync which isn't possible, but how do other games navigate around this issue, to give a flawless collision experience?

What I am considering of doing:

1. Increase the position broadcasting rate from 1 time per second to however high needed to accurately sync the positions (20/sec). I believe this is the solution most games are doing. This however, will drastically increases the load on the server.
2. In my case, the game's main mechanism isn't the navigation (think MMO), so I am leaning towards only checking collision on the client side, and have a simpler collision check on the server to ban walk-through-wall hackers. This would relax the server from heavy collision operations which is nice too.

Comment: Try relying mostly on the local positioning and only correcting to the authoritative server actual position without interpolation if the local is too far away from the server's 1/sec snapshot.  Your clipping is coming from interpolating between two server snapshots that completely miss the "going around the corner" part.

Comment: @PatrickHughes Thank you for your answer. I will keep that in mind. I think the solution to this problem is just to rise the frequency of snapshots depending on how accurate one wants the movement to be synced (not so much in my case so I will keep the 1-2 updates per second snapshot). Other optimization includes reduce the range of the snapshot to be client-specific. 
Also just putting it out there, an client-only collision engine is full of flaws, and I do not recommend it after trying it out.

Comment: You could also consider sending additional updates outside of the snapshot intervals for objects that experience significant changes in position or direction.

Comment: @Romen You are right. I was thinking of sending the server positions along with the keyup/keydown events that I broadcast already. That should be more than enough to deliver a smooth gameplay 90% of the times.